# Regarding build failure on the integration stream and fixing it in UCM Clearcase environment

Tags: build, clearcase-ucm

We have a good UCM Clearcase system. We have proper nightly builds on the integration stream and I have configured CruiseControl.NET for various sites.

The issue is that in case of build failures, no baseline is applied. This forces developers to fix the issues on the build server itself.

This is highly undesirable. I want to apply a baseline and make it **REJECT**ed. Then ask the developer to fix issues by rebasing against the REJECTed baseline.

How should I do that in the following stream configuration:

```
MainStream

    |
    |---Germany_Stream
           |
          / \
          Multiple developer streams
    |
    |---USA_Stream
           |
          / \
          Multiple developer streams
```

The developers deliver changesets to their sites. That is German devs to German stream and US devs to US stream.

These changes are then pushed to the MainStream. The nightly build happens there. A baseline should be applied at the MainStream and recommended in case the build passes. If it fails the baseline needs to be applied and **REJECT**ed. How do I make the **REJECT**ed baseline available to the developers who are two levels below the MainStream?

Please let me know how I can make developers follow best practices and stop them from making changes in the build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I make the *REJECT*ed baseline available to the developers who are two levels below the MainStream?

If you are thinking rebase, you would need to rebase on site stream (USA or Germany), *then* rebase dev streams.

That can be a good approach as each stream can choose to rebase (pull approach) from the site stream to their dev stream.
The only issue is that it requires a merge in a stream (USA or Germany) which is also used by devs for delivery: conflicts might happen.

I would recommend making a substream to Main, called `Rejected_Stream`, which can be rebased at will (and will get the latest `REJECT` baseline).
From there, any dev can choose to initiate a deliver from that stream to their own dev stream.

The problem with this approach is that each deliver would have to be made *sequentially*.

Comment: Thanks VonC. What is the best practice or practices when it comes to fixing build issues on the main stream? Developers fixing the issue on the build server might not be good at all in any case as it unnecessarily opens the server to developers and more importantly, the history of the file gets messed up.

Comment: @msiyer the problem is the propagation of the fixes done on Main. What is fixed on Main might not be relevant anymore on dev, which might have evolved differently. Allowing dev to see what need to be fixed, through baseline `REJECT` on a dedicated Stream), while keeping the delivery mechanism one way (dev=>site=>Main) allows for a simpler history.

Comment: My post and comments are based on logical assumptions I made after watching the FLOW of CODE in UCM for a few months. I feel I have made correct assumptions. Thank you VonC. You have always been a beacon of hope for this lone Ranger in the dark code jungle :)